# TypeError: $.UIkit.sticky is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit, sticky

About a month ago I discovered my navbar was no longer sticky, and my console displayed the error: TypeError: $.UIkit.sticky is not a function

The console references three files with this error:

```
/theme.js:20:17
dispatch /media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:3:12392
add/r.handle /media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:3:9156
```

For theme.js the offending code is `$.UIkit.sticky(navbar, (function(){`
For dispatch /media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:3:12392 the offending code is `.apply(f.elem,i),void 0!==d&&`
For add/r.handle /media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:3:9156 the offending code is `.apply(k.elem,arguments)},k.elem=a),b=(b||"")`

I am not experienced in JS per se, but I can usually find a logical solution. However, in this particular case, I have been unable to locate a solution. I have evaluated the files looking for mispellings or some other format error to no avail. I even have a slightly older version of the site on a test server and I compared the code in each file; they were the exact same despite the sticky function working properly on the older, test site.

I've searched for any reference to a similar issue and, while I did find one similar issue, it did not yield any helpful information.

Comment: are you using a framework that would explain the change? (framework update, resource version changes, etc)

Comment: Joomla. I would say on/around the time that I noticed the error was about the time we upgraded from 3.7.3 to 3.7.4, but it was a really minor update. Also, I *think* the timeline of the update and this issue are aligned, but they may not be. Further, I haven't seen a single reference to this being an issue (in the past 1-2 months) anywhere, including Joomla forums.

Comment: sorry to ask, no time to search, worked with joomla but forgotten that: is this the general jQuery used by joomla? I know some components use their own modified versions of jQuery or bootstrap..

Comment: Honestly, no clue. I'm not very familiar with jQuery and how it is used within Joomla.

Comment: are you using a custom theme? one you got somewhere? From searching, i have found no apparent link between jQuery and UIkit, they seem different stuff. Do you have something useful if you do `console.log($.UIkit); console.log(UIkit);` in a `$(document).ready` (or similar, the function you use for page loaded event)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is UIkit3 now the old UIkit is called UIkit2.
If you need `UIkit.sticky()` just change it to `UIkit2.sticky()`

Answer (score 0):

Change in your theme.js on line 44 or close to that:

```
$.UIkit.sticky($('.tm-navbar'), (function(){
```

to new

```
UIkit2.sticky($('.tm-navbar'), (function(){
```